# Best practice for undoing changes you made many commits ago?

Tags: git, github

Situations like the following happen quite often when I'm using Github and I'm not sure I'm going about them the right way.

Example. A few days ago, I added some libraries to `requirements.txt` file, committed and pushed the changes. Then I did a few days work and made more commits and pushes to other files. I didn't change `requirements.txt` at all.

Today, I realise I don't actually need the libraries I added to `requirements.txt` and want to remove them.

The easy thing would be to delete the unneeded libraries, make a commit, and push. But this feels too linear. Is there a more 'proper' way to do it? Should I go back in time and take the old file instead? Perhaps branch at that commit and move all the other work onto this branch? I feel like by adding a new commit that just undoes my previous one, it could clutter up the commit history?

Comment: Too linear? More proper? What is the problem you're trying to solve? (unclear history? time-consuming? other?) I wouldn't call "clutter up" a simple do-and-undo.

Comment: I assumed that the changes you make in git should be kept for a while. If you make a change then undo it a few commits later, this seemed 'unproper' to me for some reason. I'm self-taught and mainly work on small projects. I was worried this was a bad habit I might propagate into larger projects. Hence the question. I'm glad this doesn't seem to be cluttering up.

Comment: "*If you make a change then undo it a few commits later*" --> This happens all the time in most projects. Git records history. It also faithfully records these back-and-forth changes. An analogy would be someone looking at an album photo and saying "Oh, this photo of me as a kid is wrong since now I'm a bearded man. Better destroy it." No you should not. It adequately depicts how you looked like at the time.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what you would like to get as the history of the project... *and* if you will mess up other people's work.

If you are working with more people and they have already picked up that work (it's part of a shared branch, for example), then you should *not* rewrite history. Just commit the changes on the file (perhaps with a revert of that original revision) and move forward. You could still rewrite history of the project if you *reeeeeeeeally* needed/wanted to, but it creates additional work and synchronization effort to not mess it up once you have rewritten history of the branch.

If you are on your own or working on a feature branch that no one else is working on, you could consider rewriting history of the branch (with a `git rebase -i` is good enough) so that it looks like the change on the file never happened.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your overall workflow. If you are still working on a feature branch or changes were only made locally you could use

1. [`git revert {ID}`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)
   or
2. [`git rebase -i {ID-Before-Commit}`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---interactive)

For work I haven't shared yet I would probably go with option 2. It is usable for many scenarios and is worth to be familiar with. [Read more](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)

However, if you've already shared your changes with others it might be better just to add another commit with a proper message. In this case `git revert {Id}` can be used to 'undo' a complete commit.